# Problem About Surface Area

Tags: surfaces, spheres

The  surface area of sphere with $r$ that is made by play dough is $A_1$. The surface area of cylinder is being $A_2$ when that's  made by this sphere. What is the ratio of $\frac {A_1}{A_2}$?

I've tried to get what is meant in question.

$$A_1 = A_2$$

By the way

$$4 \pi r^2 = 2\pi r h + 2\pi r^2$$

and

$$2\pi r^2 = 2 \pi r h$$

According to me, the surface area of sphere must be equal to the surface area of cylinder.

The answer seems $\frac {6}{7}$ on my textbook. How did we arrive at that answer?

Might I get your hints?

Comment: The question seems to be worded badly; 'All surface area is being $A_2$' simply doesn't make grammatical sense. However, if they are looking for a ratio, then your answer is $\frac{4\pi r^2}{2 \pi r h + 2\pi r^2} = \frac {2\pi r} {r+h}$.

Comment: @Landuros You are right but the answer seems $\frac {6}{7}$. That's why I didn't get what question means.

Comment: See new edit. I've fixed my grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume of the sphere is equal to the volume of the cylinder, so
$$\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 = \pi r^2 h\,.$$
Rearrange this to get
$$h=\frac{4}{3}r.$$
Thus
$$\frac{A_1}{A_2}=\frac{4\pi r^2}{2\pi r^2+2\pi rh}.$$
Substituting $h=\frac{4}{3}r$, you will find $\frac{A_1}{A_2}=\frac{6}{7}$.

Comment: Why aren't surfaces equal?

Comment: The same amount of play dough (same volume of material) is used to make both the cylinder and the sphere, so the volumes are equal, not the surface areas

Comment: I still couldn't find $\frac{A_1}{A_2}=\frac{6}{7}$

Comment: $\frac{A_1}{A_2}=\frac{4\pi r^2}{2\pi r^2+2\pi rh}=\frac{2r}{r+h}=\frac{2r}{r+\frac{4}{3}r}=\frac{2}{1+\frac{4}{3}}=\frac{2}{7/3}=\frac{6}{7}$